# How To_decimal works in Informatica

Tags: sql-server, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Today i came across an issue in informatica  code which i have figured out the solution for it. But i don’t have a proper justification and not sure if my solution is a proper fix.

Here is the summary of my issue:

**Source:** Flatfile (Fixed Width)

**Source Field Datatype:** String 14

**Target:** SQL Server Table

**Targer Field Datatype:** Decimal (14,2)

**Old Logic**
IIF (TO_DECIMAL(FIELDNAME),TO_DECIMAL(FIELDNAME)/100,NULL)

**Bad data**
00002631064132

**Error**
Message: Transformation Evaluation Error [<> [TO_INTEGER]: integer overflow
... i:TO_INTEGER(f:TO_FLOAT(d2:TO_DECIMAL(u:'00002631064132',i:-100)),i:0)]

**Updated Logic**
IIF(NOT ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(FIELDNAME))),TO_DECIMAL(FIELDNAME)/100,NULL)

**Output**
26310641.32 (Loaded as Expected)

**Issue Summary**

We have the initial logic (Old Logic) which converts the string to decimal(14,2).

This code has been running without any issues since from a while. But today this load has failed with integer overflow (Error).

I have changed the logic as show in the picture(Updated logic) and it loaded the data successfully with expected output(Output).

My doubt is why there is to_integer, to_float showed up in the error when i’m not using anywhere in my mapping. I’m looking for proper justification for this fix.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is this `TO_DECIMAL()` function? Is this a custom function? This is tagged as sql-server, but I do not think this function is part of SQL Server. Also, `ISNULL()` would expect 2 arguments in SQL Server.

Comment: @MatthewI This is an inbuilt function in informatica. My target table is in sql server.

Comment: I would have to see the data that you are using. Can you put in a table and specify the data types of the columns?

Comment: It seems 2631064132 is above 2^31 and the TO_DECIMAL function doesn't handle it correctly by default. Try to enable the High Precision option in the session, it may help for this kind of values.

Comment: @MatthewI Hi Matthew. Thanks for your response apparently i have modified my updated logic in the iif condition to is_number function and it is also worked.

Comment: @MickaëlBucas i dont this is an issue : i see this from the guide :"Note: If the return value is Decimal with precision greater than 15, you can enable high precision to ensure decimal precision up to 28 digits. " In this case the value is just 14 digits. we have to look into the -100 value for scale as probable cause for the issue.

Answer (score -1):

What is the data type of the variable/output port where you are logic is defined ?
Also can you provide the input data that was causing this issue ?

Comment: The datatype of the variable port is decimal(14,2) and the input data is the ‘0002631064132’.

Comment: Thanks Rohan., I agree with what Mickael has suggested